# Convert integer value to a float value with step size depending on range

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I've got a slider which I use to vary a parameter (`y`) that can have a wide range of values. The position of the slider is given as an integer (`x`).

My parameter holds the energy of a source, and can have values from 0.1 nJ all the way up to 10 J. For application purposes I would like the parameter step size to be:

- 0.1 nJ in [0.1 nJ - 1.0 µJ]
- 0.1 µJ in [1.0 µJ - 1.0 mJ]
- 0.1 mJ in [1.0 mJ - 1.0  J]
- 0.1  J in [1.0  J - 10.0 J]

I'm trying to convert these values (`x => y`) by using the integer division (`//`) and remainder (`%`) operations, but I run in to problems when I get cross over from one sub range to another, for example.

x = 9999 gives y = 999.9 nJ, which it should, but then x = 10000 gives y = 0.0 µJ, which is then 0 in the system and much lower than 999.9 nJ. The next step (x = 10001) gives y = 0.1 µJ which is also lower than 999.9 nJ.

Ideally the steps of y should be 999.9 nJ - 1.0 µJ - 1.1 µJ.

This MWE uses [key detection](http://www.jonwitts.co.uk/archives/896) to read the input of keys without having to press ENTER.

```
import math as m
import sys, termios, tty, os, time

prefixes =   {-18:'a', -15:'f', -12:'p', -9:'n',    # Prefixes for displaying the value
        -6:'\u03bc', -3:'m', #-2:'c', -1:'d',
        +0:'', #+1:'da', +2:'h', 
        +3:'k', +6:'M', +9:'G', +12:'T', +15:'P', +18:'E'}

def getch():                    # Get character from keyboard without waiting for enter
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

def calcy():                        # Convert from x integer to y value for display
    print("x: " + repr(x))
    exp2 = 3*((x/resolution) // 1e+3) + exp0    # integer division
    yp2 = round((x/resolution)%(1e+3), digits)  # remainder
    y2 = round(yp2 * m.pow(10, exp2), int(digits-exp2))
    print("y: " + repr(y2) + "   equal to " + repr(yp2) + str(prefixes[exp2]) + "J\n")

button_delay = 0.1

y = float(input("Give starting value:"))    # Choose a value to start from

exp0 = -9                                     # Exponent of minimum range [nJ]
digits = 1                                  # Number of decimals to be used
resolution = m.pow(10, 1)                   # The number of points for a change of size 1

exp = 0                                     # Exponent of y
yp = y                                      # Short number of y
while yp < 1/resolution:                    # While the number is not in the prefixed unit
    yp = yp*1e+03                           # Multiply yp by 1000 (10³)
    exp -= 3                                # Exponent increases by 3

yp = round(y * m.pow(10, -exp), digits)     # The display value 
x = int((yp + (exp - exp0)/3 * 1e+3) * resolution)   # Integer value representing the silder value

calcy()                                     # Calculate y from x integer

while True:
    char = getch()            # Get pressed key

    if char == 'q':           # If it was q, quit
        exit(0)
    elif char == '+':         # If it was +, increase x by one and
        x += 1                # recalculate y
        calcy()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    elif char == '-':        # If it was -, decrease x by one and 
        x -= 1               # recalculate y
        calcy()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    else:
        print(char)
        time.sleep(button_delay)
```

If you want to try this program, I recommend giving `500e-9` as the starting value and pushing `-` 6 times to get to y = 999.9 nJ as that is where things go wrong.

I understand that it's logical for x = 10001 to convert to 0.1 µJ with the algorithm I am using but I don't know how to solve it. If you could only change the value with the `+` and `-` buttons one could go directly from 9999 to 10011, which would logically give y = 1.1 µJ, but how would I then handle the fact that the actual slider can be dragged with the mouse?

Please give me any ideas you have on how to solve this.

Comment: I suspect the problem would be much easier to handle if you modularized your code: define a function that takes `x` and chooses an appropriate value depending on its range. You could hard-wire the four ranges you expect to cover, and for a given range you can probably figure it out easier what analytical form you want to use to map `x` to energy. Or I guess `calcy` does just that...but then this is my suggestion: use explicit `if` branches to handle the various ranges independently.

Comment: The issue with that is that the ranges vary depending on user definitions. A user can add a new object with a different energy range. But thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and the suggestion from @Davis-Herring I think I have solved it. The function now can be adjusted for different resolutions (steps sizes) and starting exponents (exp0).

```
def calcy(x):
    if x < (1000*resolution - 1):        # The number of values from the start to the first prefix change
        exp = exp0
        yp = round((x + 1)/resolution, digits) # Round to account for numerical discrepancies
    else:
        n = round((1000 - 1) * resolution) # The number of values in all other ranges
        z = round(x - (1000 * resolution - 1)) # Subtract the number of values in the first range
        r = z // n + 1          # The number of passed ranges
        yp = round((z % n)/resolution + 1, digits)
        exp = exp0 + 3 * r
    return yp * 10**exp
```

With `resolution = 10` and `digits = 1` each step in the first range is 0.1 nJ, and then 0.1 µJ, 0.1mJ ......

Answer (score 1):

You have 9999 values in each half-open interval and 90 in the last, closed interval, because (for example) 10000(0.1 nJ)=1 µJ.  This makes the conversion easy:

```
def val(x):   # 0<=x<30,087
  r,x=divmod(x,9999)
  return (x+1)*1000**(r-3)/10
```

(There’s something in the comments about extending to support other ranges, but it’s not specific enough to answer.)

Comment: Nice idea, but how do I modify it so that it doesn't use 3? That is, in the example the minimum value is 0.1 nJ, but in the application the user can add a parameter for which the minimum value is 0.1 fH (10^-15) or 0.1 kW. That is why my example code uses `exp0` as a reference exponent. Also, the number of digits and resolution can be changed by the user so `1000**(r-3)` wont work in that case.

Comment: Also, just realized that x = 0 gives 1 nJ and not 0.1 nJ.

Comment: @Kajsa: I fixed the 0.1; that was just an oversight.  As for generalizing, obviously 3 can be a parameter to set the starting point, but I don’t know what “number of digits and resolution can be changed” means.

Comment: @Kajsa: Maybe you just want `10**(a*r+b)` with customizable *a* and *b* (here, 3 and -10) and `10**c-1` as the modulus (here *c* is 4)?